# BigQuery RANK() over many columns at once

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table in BigQuery of the following structure:

`my_table`

```
name    num1    num2    num3    num4
joe     12      15      11      8
tom     15      18      13      11
bill    19      11      12      23
nick    27      13      16      15
sal      9      12      16      5
chris   13      19      25      23
```

and would like to create 4 additional columns, each of which outputs the rank of 1 of the 4 num* columns. My objective then is:

```
name    num1    num2    num3    num4    num1_rk    num2_rk    num3_rk    num4_rk
joe     12      15      11      8       2          4          ...
tom     15      18      13      11      4          5
bill    19      11      12      23      5          1
nick    27      13      16      15      6          3
sal      9      12      16      5       1          2
chris   13      19      25      23      3          6
```

I can achieve the following by applying the `RANK()` function in the `SELECT` call to each of the 4 columns, however this is not ideal for my use case.

```
SELECT
  *,
  RANK() OVER (ORDER BY num1 ASC) AS num1_rank,
  RANK() OVER (ORDER BY num2 ASC) AS num2_rank,
  ...
FROM my_table
```

I have a very wide table with 50+ (and rising) metrics that each need a ranking. Is there a way to do this without having to apply the PERCENT_RANK() column 50+ times?

Comment: I think the best approach is to convert my table from wide to long, then partition over the different metrics when applying the `percent_rank`, and then convert back to wide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is the closest to what you ask for

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * FROM my_table JOIN (
  SELECT name, STRING_AGG(CAST(num_rank AS STRING) ORDER BY OFFSET) ranks 
  FROM (
    SELECT name, OFFSET, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY OFFSET ORDER BY CAST(num AS INT64)) AS num_rank
    FROM my_table t,
    UNNEST(SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(FORMAT('%t', t), r'[() ]', ''))) num WITH OFFSET
    WHERE OFFSET > 0
    ORDER BY OFFSET
  ) GROUP BY name
) USING(name)
```

If to apply to sample data from your question - output will be

```
Row name    num1    num2    num3    num4    ranks    
1   joe     12      15      11      8       2,4,1,2  
2   tom     15      18      13      11      4,5,3,3  
3   bill    19      11      12      23      5,1,2,5  
4   nick    27      13      16      15      6,3,4,4  
5   sal     9       12      16      5       1,2,4,1  
6   chris   13      19      25      23      3,6,6,5
```

As you can see, above does not have dependency on number of num columns - but expects them to start from second - this can be adjusted to whatever real data you have

Also, if you want to output ranks as array instead of string - you can use

```
ARRAY_AGG(num_rank ORDER BY OFFSET) ranks
```

instead of

```
STRING_AGG(CAST(num_rank AS STRING) ORDER BY OFFSET) ranks
```

with output

[image]